# How to replace Symbols and characters in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
+----------+
| average  |
+----------+
|77<@>1    |
+----------+
```

How do I replace <@> with . ?

Expected Output:

```
+----------+
| average  |
+----------+
|77.1      |
+----------+
```

I tried `df.withColumn("average", regexp_replace($"average","[<@>]","."))` and the output was

```
+----------+
| average  |
+----------+
|77...1    |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put square brackets. That's not necessary as you want to replace the whole string <@>. If you put square brackets, each char that matches <, @, or > will be replaced with a dot.

```
df.withColumn("average", regexp_replace($"average","<@>",".")).show()

+-------+
|average|
+-------+
|   77.1|
+-------+
```